# Unable to correctly set NGINX rewrite with proxy pass directives

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm currently working on a legacy API which runs on an old Symfony version (2.8 in the process of upgrading to 3.4).

The application has two 'main' PHP entrypoints: `app_dev.php` and `app.php`. The `_dev` endpoint is only supposed to be used in development environments however has been used incorrectly on an old production application.

We can easily modify the API to avoid exposing this file (and have done successfully), however, we cannot easily update some of the applications connecting to the API. For example, some applications are still trying to connect using `https://domain/app_dev.php/the/path`.

As a temporary solution whilst we work to fix the applications which are consuming the API, we'd like to re-write a URL such as `https://domain/app_dev.php/the/path` to `https://domain/app.php/the/path` or even better to `https://domain/the/path`. *We believe that rewrite is the correct option here but maybe we are not correct?*

We have the current configuration for NGINX:

```
## nginx.conf
user                    www-data;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections          4096;
}

http {
    server_tokens           off;

    include                 /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type            application/octet-stream;

    # log_format must come before access_log!
    log_format              main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status '
                                 '$body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile                    on;
    keepalive_timeout           65;
    client_max_body_size        50M;
    proxy_buffer_size           128k;
    proxy_buffers               4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

```
## php-prod.conf
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen                      80;

    client_max_body_size        50M;
    client_body_buffer_size     128k;
    fastcgi_param               REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

    root                        /var/www/web;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files               $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Configuration for PHP passthrough on remote / production endpoints
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-custom-auth, content-type, x-requested-with, authorization, mobile";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
            add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
            return 204;
        }

        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the current version of your application, you
        # should pass the real application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP FPM. Otherwise, PHP's OPcache
        # may not properly detect changes to your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404: http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # Return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller.
    # This prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log off;
}
```

I have tried to add `rewrite /app_dev\.php/(.*) /app.php$1 break;` into a variety of places including the main `server` block and the `location /` block and cannot seem to get the redirect to work. I've tried using `break` and `last` but I just get a 500 response from the API with no content.

If I update `location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {` to `location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {` it works without issue so I know the API is 'working' behind NGINX.

I should mention that a 301 redirect will not work here since I need to rewrite POST requests as well. However, I have tested it as a 301 redirect instead and I get the expected result (but 301 will not work for us for POST requests):

```
    location / {
        rewrite /app_dev\.php/(.*) /$1 permanent;
        try_files               $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

...

127.0.0.1 - testCommand [25/May/2023:09:04:31 +0000] "POST /app_dev.php/api/path HTTP/1.0" 301 162 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2"
172.20.0.1 - testCommand [25/May/2023:09:04:31 +0000] "POST /app_dev.php/api/path HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [25/May/2023:09:04:31 +0000] "GET /api/path HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "https://api.domain.com/app_dev.php/api/path" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2"
```

If I set this to break:

```
172.20.0.1 - testCommand [25/May/2023:09:08:05 +0000] "POST /app_dev.php/api/path HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2" "-"
127.0.0.1 - testCommand [25/May/2023:09:08:05 +0000] "POST /app_dev.php/api/path HTTP/1.0" 500 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2"
```

If I set this to last:

```
172.20.0.1 - testCommand [25/May/2023:09:13:57 +0000] "POST /app_dev.php/api/path HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2" "-"
127.0.0.1 - testCommand [25/May/2023:09:13:57 +0000] "POST /app_dev.php/api/path HTTP/1.0" 500 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2"
```

So my question is how to get this rewrite working in the way that a URL such as `https://domain/app_dev.php/the/path` is rewritten to `https://domain/app.php/the/path` or even better to `https://domain/the/path`?

Answer (score 0):

You tried `rewrite /app_dev\.php/(.*) /app.php$1 break;`, but **break** is the wrong flag - you need to use **last**. See the [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

---

Alternatively, to redirect a POST request, you could use a [307 status response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307), for example:

```
location ~ ^/app_dev\.php(/|$) {
    return 307 /app.php$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Make sure you place this above the `location ~ \.php$` block.

I notice the `location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$)` block is marked `internal` which would prevent your server from responding to external requests for `/app.php`. Which seems to contradict some of the statements in your question.

Comment: You are right about the `internal` stopping it being accessed via `app.php/...`. I didn't notice that before. It's using that internally and on the external side not using any php file prefix.

Comment: I've tried:

```
    location ~ ^/app_dev\.php(/|$) {
        rewrite /app_dev\.php(/|$) $1 last;
    }
```

Unfortunately it's passing `/app_dev.php/path` through to the PHP FPM instance which is returning 'No route found ...'. Do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: Your PHP script is probably using the REQUEST_URI parameter, which is set to the value of the original request. The simplest solution is to use "return 307". Alternatively, copy&paste `location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$)` into `location ~ ^/app_dev\.php(/|$)` and override the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_URI` parameters.